# WiThings API OAuth with Python

Tags: python, api, github, oauth

I've really been struggling with getting OAuth to work with the WiThings API lately, using Python 3.3. For reference, here is the documentation for WiThings: http://www.withings.com/api

Now... As I've said, I have been working with the WiThings API in Python, using the requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Supposedly, this has built in support for OAuth 1.0.

Using this, when I put in my consumer key and consumer secret, then perform the token request, I get this response...

```
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>\nThe requested resource<br />/index.php<br />\ndoes not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in\nthe request exceeds the capacity limit.\n<hr>\n<address>Apache Server at oauth.withings.com Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n'
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I have a feeling its WiThings specific... but their support is horrible.

Next, I did some more research, and found this: https://github.com/maximebf/python-withings

While also rather poorly documented, I installed it, and have this code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import withings

CONSUMER_KEY = "omitted"

CONSUMER_SECRET = "omitted"

auth = WithingsAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
authorize_url = auth.get_authorize_url()
print("Go to %s allow the app and copy your oauth_verifier" %authorize_url)
oauth_verifier = raw_input('Please enter your oauth_verifier: ')
creds = auth.get_credentials(oauth_verifier)

client = WithingsApi(creds)
measures = client.get_measures(limit=1)
print("Your last measured weight: %skg" % measures[0].weight)
```

And get the following error...

```
File "withings.py", line 5, in <module>
   import withjings
File C:\User_Directory\withings.py", line 11, in <module>
   auth = WithingsAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
NameError: name 'WithingsAuth' is not defined
```

Any help on either of these issues? Has anyone had success working with Withings in python?

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
from withings import WithingsAuth, WithingsApi
```

For me it works well I was able to extract my last measured weight.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to import WithingsAuth from withings, or specify that you want to use the withings.WithingsAuth. Changing your code it becomes:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
try:
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs
except:
    import urlparse as parse_qs

try:
    input_method = raw_input
except:
    input_method = input

import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import withings

CONSUMER_KEY = "omitted"

CONSUMER_SECRET = "omitted"

auth = withings.WithingsAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
authorize_url = auth.get_authorize_url()
print("Go to %s allow the app and copy your oauth_verifier" %authorize_url)
oauth_verifier = input_method('Please enter your oauth_verifier: ')
creds = auth.get_credentials(oauth_verifier)

client = withings.WithingsApi(creds)
measures = client.get_measures(limit=1)
print("Your last measured weight: %skg" % measures[0].weight)
```